# str::String return from function

Tags: c++

I want to return std::string str can somebody fill up ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void display(std::string str) {
    std::cout << str << "\n";
    return  ?
}

int main() {
    std::string str = "Message";
    ? = display(str);
}
```

Comment: you can't return anything from a `void` function

Comment: Sounds like you could use a [good C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Comment: On another note, why should **`display`** *return* anything? What problem is that supposed to solve? Perhaps you should name the function something better if it's supposed to do more than just *display* the string.

Answer (score 2):

If what you want is to display the string, you can simply have :

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void display(std::string str) {
    std::cout << str << "\n";
}

int main() {
    std::string str = "Message";
    display(str);
}
```

But if what you want is to get the `string` back from `dispaly()` ( which is useless as it'll be the same value as `str` ); then you can have something like this :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string display(std::string str) {
    std::cout<<str<< "\n";
    return  str;
}

int main() {
    std::string str = "Message";
    std::string stringFromDisplay=display(str);
}
```

Comment: thanks this is what i am looking for, hey can we assign ```std::string stringFromDisplay``` to some local variables like  string a or char a[]

Comment: Well in my answer `stringFromDisplay` is a local variable, so you can use it as it is